# google script "insertHtml is not a function"

Tags: google-apps-script

Getting error in

> Type Error body.insertHtml is not a function.

```
function replacePlaceholdersWithHtml() {
  // Open the Google Docs document
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById('YOUR_DOCUMENT_ID');
  var body = doc.getBody();

  // Define your HTML content to replace placeholders
  var htmlContent1 = '<p>This is HTML content for Placeholder1</p>';
  var htmlContent2 = '<div><strong>This is HTML content for Placeholder2</strong></div>';

  // Get the document content as text
  var content = body.getText();

  // Replace placeholders with HTML content
  content = content.replace('{{Placeholder1}}', htmlContent1);
  content = content.replace('{{Placeholder2}}', htmlContent2);

  // Clear the existing content in the document body
  body.clear();

  // Insert the updated content as HTML
  body.insertHtml(0, content);
  
  // Save the changes
  doc.saveAndClose();
}
```

I am expecting above to work.

Comment: Why do you want to insert HTML?  The Google [Document](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document) is not HTML.

Answer (score 1):

There's no such method as insertHtml() on Body objects.
Check the full docs here:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body

Maybe `body.insertParagraph(0, content)` is more what you're looking for

Comment: There is a document.getElementById("").innerHTML=""